# "guiding the tool"

Tags: grammaticality

> The programmer can set breakpoints guiding the tool to freeze the program execution at specific control locations.

Is the use of *guiding* in the sentence above correct? If it is correct, what grammar rule makes it correct?

Comment: Syntactically, that is correct. Semantically, it's a little weird, but understandable. I would probably write "*causing* the tool to freeze the program execution..."

Comment: @Daniel but what is guilding modified? is this a participial phrase?

Comment: yes it is a participial phrase. The object of "guiding" is "the tool"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Guide* as verb is used to express the following meanings:

- Show the way
- Influence behavior
- Explain
- Help somebody move

The second point could seem to apply to your case, but in that case *guide* is used as in the following sentence.

> He was always guided by his religious beliefs.

In your case, I agree with @Daniel that *causing* is the verb I would use.

> The programmer can set breakpoints, causing the tool to freeze the program at specific control locations.

You could also make the sentence shorter.

> The programmer can set breakpoints which freeze the program at specific control locations.

In the latter sentence, it is not clear that the tool freezes the program; if that is clear from a previous sentence, it is not necessary to make it explicit in that sentence too.

Comment: Thanks, "..causing the tool to freeze the program at specific control locations.", what phrase (e.g., noun phrase, etc) is it?

Comment: It's a participial phrase.

Comment: But what is the participial phase modifies?

Comment: It modifies _the programmer_.